# How to add dragstart handler to Fullcalendar Draggable

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, draggable

I have some external events that I want to drag and drop on the calendar. I would like to run some code when an external event is dragged but I can not find a nice way to add such a handler to a Draggable event.

I've been able to add a handler in a hacky way to the _handlers array but surely there must be a better way. I have also tried the default HTML "ondragstart" event but it seems to be replaced by Draggable.

```
const draggable = new Draggable(element, {
  eventData: { ... }
});
draggable.dragging.emitter._handlers.dragstart.push(() => console.log("dragstart!"));
```

I expected there to be an option for the Draggable constructor where I could provide a dragstart handler but I can not find one in the documentation.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging says "you may leverage a 3rd-party drag and drop library instead". So it fullCalendar's draggable doesn't do what you need, maybe you would need to look into that

Comment: @ADyson I have tried the ThirdPartyDraggable with react-dnd but was not successful. (I'm building a React app but I don't think this issue is related to the FullCalendar React package)